# javax.naming.NamingException: JNDI lookup failed with IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using JNDI lookup with JMS.

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext(env);
context.lookup("jms/cf");
```

The same code is working fine with eclipse IDE. But when I am trying with IntelliJ it is giving following Issue.

```
JNDI lookup failed - null
javax.naming.NamingException: JNDI lookup failed - null
    at com.solacesystems.jndi.SolJNDIInitialContextFactory$SolJNDIInitialContextImpl.lookup(SolJNDIInitialContextFactory.java:216)
```

Do anyone have idea if anything specific in IntelliJ settings.

Answer (score 0):

After checked all things found that It was because I am using java policy file and do not have correct permissions for Socket Connections and Environment variables.

Added following in policy file and it is working for me
 permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getenv.*";
 permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:1024-", "accept,connect,listen";